# apache mod_rewrite fails when file by same name exists

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

The complete .htaccessfile

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/(index\.php)?$ /main.php?type=$1&action=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

so,

```
www.server.com/users/new/
```

redirects to:

```
www.server.com/main.php?type=users&action=new
```

**The rule works fine on my test machine.**

---

**However**,
on another machine, it fails *if there is a file that starts with the same name*:

```
/
|- main.php
|
+--[users]
    |- new.inc.js
```

requesting

```
www.server.com/users/list/       --> 200 OK (main.php returns results as expected)
www.server.com/users/new/        --> 404 Not Found
```

If I remove `new.inc.js' the request will be redirected as expected.

**What configuration flag causes this behaviour?**
(I've been banging my head against the wall for some time now)

**Update**
(I added the complete .htaccess file contents)
`index.html` and `index.php` are the directory indexes

(And it does not make sense to me either :()

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me yet from the information presented. Are there other RewriteRules? Is index.php set as the default index file?

Comment: Just to be clear, requesting www.server.com/users/new/ when <ROOT_DIR>/users/new/new.inc.js exist give a 404 error ?
Could you enable rewrite log and give us the result ? 
(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Comment: @radius: <document_root>/users/new.inc.js exists. Unfortunately I can't enable anything. It took a lot of talking for me to get read access to the config files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have [`mod_negotiation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html) installed?  If so, that'll take your request for new and try to work out what file you really meant to send.  Make sure you don't have `Options MultiViews` set. So, in the `.htaccess` put `Options -MultiViews`.